# Use jQuery to get attribute value of a <source> element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get an attribute value from a `<source>` element using jQuery. `<source ix-path="example.com/something.jpg">`

```
$("[ix-path*='something']").each(function (index, element) {
    let path = $(element).attr('ix-path');
    console.log('path: ', path);
});
```

My code also has the attribute `ix-path` in `<img>` elements and this code works just fine getting them.

I've considered that `attr()` only gets the value of the first matched element. However, that shouldn't be the issue since I have it in an `each()` function and it will get the value of `ix-path` from multiple `<img>` elements. Is it because `<source>` is an empty element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$(element)`

```js
$("[ix-path*='x']").each(function(index, element) {
  let path = $(this).attr('ix-path');
  console.log('path: ', path);
});
```

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src='file.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' ix-path='x0'>
</audio>
<audio controls>
  <source src='file.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' ix-path='x1'>
</audio>
<audio controls>
  <source src='file.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' ix-path='x2'>
</audio>
<audio controls>
  <source src='file.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' ix-path='x3'>
</audio>
<audio controls>
  <source src='file.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' ix-path='x4'>
</audio>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```